# Find a value in an unordered_set of shared_ptr

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, unordered-set

I'd like to find a value in unordered_set, but failed:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<int> IntPtr;

std::unordered_set<IntPtr> s;
s.insert(std::make_shared<int>(42));

bool found = s.find(std::make_shared<int>(42)) != s.end();
cout<<std::boolalpha<<found<<endl; // false
```

Had tried following but still not working.

```
namespace std {
  template <> struct hash<IntPtr> {
    size_t operator()(const IntPtr& x) const noexcept {
      return std::hash<int>()(*x);
    }
  };
}
```

Any idea how to make it works?

Comment: You need to understand what it means for two shared pointers to be "equal".

Comment: You should not specialize `std::hash` not for **your** type...

Comment: Comparison operators for `shared_ptr` compare pointer values; the actual objects pointed to are not compared.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You stored a *pointer* to an integer. When you look up items in the set, you're not comparing the (pointed-to) integer, but the pointer itself.

When you allocate a *new* pointer to a *new* integer object for the search, it won't compare equal, because it's a different integer object (even though it stores the same value).

Your options are:

1. don't store pointers to integers in your set, just store the integers directly.

   Then, your key is `42`, and searching for `42` will find it, because the integers are compared by value
2. store pointers and use a custom hash and comparator to compare the *pointed-at integers* instead of the pointers.

   You shouldn't (try to) pollute `std` namespace with your hash specialization, and it's not sufficient anyway (the hash is used for bucket lookup, but keys are still compared with `KeyEqual` inside the bucket). Just specify them *for your container*.

Example code for #2:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <memory>
#include <unordered_set>

namespace Deref {
    struct Hash {
        template <typename T>
        std::size_t operator() (std::shared_ptr<T> const &p) const {
            return std::hash<T>()(*p);
        }
    };
    struct Compare {
        template <typename T>
        size_t operator() (std::shared_ptr<T> const &a,
                           std::shared_ptr<T> const &b) const {
            return *a == *b;
        }
    };
}
    
int main() {
    std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<int>> sp;
    auto p = std::make_shared<int>(42);
    sp.insert(p);
    assert(sp.find(p) != sp.end()); // same pointer works
    assert(sp.find(std::make_shared<int>(42)) == sp.end()); // same value doesn't

    // with the correct hash & key comparison, both work
    std::unordered_set<std::shared_ptr<int>, Deref::Hash, Deref::Compare> spd;
    spd.insert(p);
    assert(spd.find(p) != spd.end());
    assert(spd.find(std::make_shared<int>(42)) != spd.end());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp):

> Note that the comparison operators for shared_ptr simply compare pointer values; the actual objects pointed to are not compared.

So `found` will be true only if `shared_ptr` points to same object:

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<int> IntPtr;

std::unordered_set<IntPtr> s;
IntPtr p = std::make_shared<int>(42);
s.insert(p);

bool found = s.find(p) != s.end();
cout<<std::boolalpha<<found<<endl; // true
```